# Working a jQuery-based autocomplete plugin into an Angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I am using a [Devbridge Ajax jQuery autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) in a directive that pulls employee names from a web api. I am having an issue updating the model when a value is selected or on blur of the field. Here is my code:

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3btyEy2xCM1aCoGqIW2J?p=preview)

and more specifically my directive:

```
app.directive('employeeName', ['employeeService', function (employeeService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            employeeService.getAll()
                .then(function (data) {
                    $(elem).devbridgeAutocomplete({
                        lookup: $.map(data, function (employee, i) {
                            return { value: employee.name, data: employee };
                        }),
                        onSelect: function () {
                            console.log('select');
                            update();
                        },
                        onInvalidateSelection: function () {
                            $(this).val('');
                        }
                    });
                });

            elem.on('blur', function () {
                console.log('blur');
                update();
            });

            var update = function () {
                var value = elem[0].value;

                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
                    ctrl.$render();
                });

                console.log(value);
                console.log(ctrl.$modelValue)
                console.log(scope.organizer);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

#### Edit: Solution

GitHub: [jQuery-Autocomplete-to-Angular](https://github.com/pmigliaccio/jQuery-Autocomplete-to-Angular)

Comment: What's not working? Seems good to me...

Comment: @Dan Issue seems to have resolved itself once I moved it into a Plunker. I'm gonna just have to dive into my code and see what else could be affecting it. Thanks for looking into it anyway.

Comment: Ok. I noticed only sub-optimal behaviour on backspace.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine when put into a Plunker...